# PowerBI - how to share a dashboard/report to All Authenticated AD Users?

Tags: javascript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a scenario where I need to embed PowerBI dashboards that I am accomplishing by doing the following:

1. Use ADAL.JS to authenticate the browser user with AD; then use an AD app to request an access token to powerbi App.
2. Pass this access token to PowerBI-Javascript (powerbi.embed) and embed a given dashboard/report into my page.

All this works fine. What I am realizing is that in order for a dashboard/report to be 'embeddable' in this manner, it **MUST** to be *shared* first. Even when I am the creator/owner of a given dashboard, it will fail to show in the embed scenario ***unless*** it is first shared (with me!). Even if the App Workspace is/App is marked public, no dice.

I can live with that.

However, what I want to do is to share all such dashboards/reports that need to be embeddable with "All authenticated AD users" so that no one ever gets an access denied error as long as they can auth against AD.

Is that possible?

(Note: the only place I have seen PowerBI offer such an "Entire Organization" option is when *publishing* an App; but publishing an App **<>** sharing an App's contents! All this is all not intuitive at all!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use several 'sharing' methods.

1. Apps are used to share artifacts (reports, dashboards) inside your organization.
2. you can use Publish to Web feature, which is the same as embedding, however this grants access to the report to everyone with the link, which makes it visible to audiences you might not want your data visible to.
3. you can use 'App owns data' scenario of Power BI Embedded, where you have one master user in AAD to authenticate against Power BI and then grant access to whoever you want.

See more about 'App owns data' in:

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi-embedded/

https://guyinacube.com/2017/10/power-bi-embedded/

https://guyinacube.com/2016/07/3-ways-to-embed-power-bi/

Comment: Thanks, but I feel that switching to "App owns data" is a bit drastic to achieve this effect.